# How to handle UP button action when child activity is invoked from 2 different parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am pretty much new to android so please forgive if I sound very much immature.

I have activity A, activity B two completely independent activities. Assume I have Activity C, which gets launched when I tap on some button in Activity A. The same activity C can also be launched by tapping some other button in Activity B.

Now my doubt is I need to show UP button on activity C. I know that I need to specify parent activity for activity C in manifest file. But here in my case I have 2 different activities one of them will be parent at any given point. So how can I specify two parents activity names for activity C? How can I dynamically handle that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to specify the `C` activity's parent in the manifest file; just intercept the click on the home button, & `finish` your activity : you shall return to the previous, caller one:

**ActivityC.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // Intercept the click on the home button
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```